# rosinstall hack to use http:// instead of git://

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently connected to my institute's network, which is causing git clone to fail. But rosinstall tries to get packages with only git clone git://

Where should i change the default protocol to http:// instead of git://

Also, when i tried changing .rosisntall file for configuring it to use http instead of git, it over wrote the thing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40560/rosinstall-hack-to-use-http://-instead-of-git:///) by [brainwave](https://answers.ros.org/users/2977/brainwave/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Download the rosinstall file:

wget http://ros.org/rosinstalls/fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

then replace all instances of "git://" with "https://" (http may work also), but do not replace the lines that say "- git".

Then when you go to install, use the local file:

rosinstall --catkin ~/ros-underlay ./fuerte-ros-full.rosinstall

This is how I have to install also

---

Originally posted by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) with karma: 506 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosinstall` should use whatever URL you gave it, with whatever scheme.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The .rosinstall file is normally where you would change the url.
The rosinstall command only overwrites the file if you call rosinstall with further arguments.

Maybe try using rosws instead:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosws

It could be easier to use.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the git protocoll/port is blocked in your network (and only then), you could try following this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891527/git-protocol-blocked-by-company-how-can-i-get-around-that

You could try this command:

```
git config --global url."http://".insteadOf git://
```

Which should add to your ~/.gitconfig:

```
[url "https://"]
   insteadOf = git://
```

However, this can also get you into trouble if you try to clone from a server that e.g. only offers git:// and https:// (not http://), so this is not a clean solution, but might still be okay for you.

If later you find out this causes more problems than it solves, just remove the added lines from your ~/.gitconfig

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PerkinsJames](https://answers.ros.org/users/2621/perkinsjames/) on 2012-08-06**:
Ah, very nice.  I didn't know how to do this without a hack.